# merge two strings based on index of character

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to write a code to merge two string based on index of character.For e.g-If we have two string "abc" and "defg",I want a string output1(merging all even character of both strings)="adcf" and another string output2="beg" (remaining all words).

**What I tried-**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string a= "First";
                string b= "MiddleName";
                string newstring = "";
             string newstring1 = "";
                int length = b.Length;
                for (int l = 0; l < length; l=l+1)
                {
                    if(l%2==0)
                    {
                    newstring = newstring + a[l].ToString() + b[l].ToString();
                }
                    if (l % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        newstring1 = newstring1 + a[l].ToString() + b[l].ToString();
                    }
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
```

But then in this case it will give outside the bound array exception.Any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your `length` must be shorter string length, after loop, append all remain characters from longer string to `newstring1`.

Comment: but then it will not take all even character of long string

Comment: `for (int l = 0; l < b.length&&  l < a.length ; l=l+1)`

Comment: @mohsen-this will do the same thing as mine and other character of longer string will be missed.

Comment: @vic90 you have to append all remain characters from longer string to `newstring1` after loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a method* where you should solve the *generalized problem* of merging two strings taking each `step` characters from them starting from `offset`:

```
private static String Merge(String left, String right, int step, int offset) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  if (null == left)
    left = ""; // or throw exception

  if (null == right)
    right = ""; // or throw exception

  for (int i = offset; i < Math.Max(left.Length, right.Length); i += step) {
    //DONE: do not forget to check if you can get a character
    if (i < left.Length)
      sb.Append(left[i]);

    //DONE: do not forget to check if you can get a character
    if (i < right.Length)
      sb.Append(right[i]);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

And so you can put it

```
 String a = "abc";
 String b = "defg";

 // adcf 
 String output1 = Merge(a, b, 2, 0); 
 // beg
 String output2 = Merge(a, b, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.Great idea

Answer (score 0):

it happens because B has longer words than A. So when its iteration is bigger than A' length, it will cause an error.
so you need to check whether A has that much word, before adding it
IF B' length always greater than A, then you can use bellow code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        string a= "First";
            string b= "MiddleName";
            string newstring = "";
         string newstring1 = "";
            int length = b.Length;
            for (int l = 0; l < length; l=l+1)
            {
                if(l%2==0)
                {
                    if(a.Length > l)
                    {newstring += a[l].ToString();}
                    newstring += b[l].ToString();
                }
                if (l % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if(a.Length > l)
                    {newstring1 += a[l].ToString();}
                    newstring1 += b[l].ToString();
                }
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int l = 0; l <  b.length && l < a.length; l++)
{
    if(l%2==0)
    {
         newstring +=  a[l]+ b[l];
     }
     if (l % 2 == 1)
     {
          newstring1 +=  a[l] + b[l];
      }
}
```